# Does a Warg feel/taste what the animal does? Does the animal become essentially human?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In season 4 episode 2 of Game of Thrones, Bran is Warging in his wolf when he is woken suddenly.

In reaction to this he cried out asking why he was woken, to which he was told that he had been gone for hours. Bran then said that he was hungry, to which he was told that he can't stay in the wolf for too long.

Wargs obviously have control over the animals they choose, so to some extent they should be able to think on their feet and react to their environment as a human would. But was there any description in the books as to how much of them was with the animal?

Which brings me to my second part of basically the same question: if they are in total control of the animal, would that not mean that Bran’s taste would also be functioning as a human, which would mean that Bran was tasting raw deer?

I can entertain the idea that hunger has taken over and it does not matter what he was eating.

### So are all the senses he has as a human with him when he is Warging?

Comment: @user568458 , Good call, but she already said she likes them in the show. But I wonder if she likes chocolate?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

The best way to answer this yourself is by simply flipping to a Bran chapter in the later books.  He goes Warging in most of them; however, for your convenience I'll put some examples in here.  This one  is from [A Wiki of Ice and Fire](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varamyr) (I couldn't find the quote in the books) concerning Varamyr's history, when he was a child and called Lump:

> Not knowing which dog had killed his son, he put down all three, killing them with an axe. Right before he split Loptail's skull, Lump slipped inside the dog's skin and felt his death. His reaction, a scream, informed Lump's parents that he was a warg.

And here's a quote of Bran as Summer in book 5:

> As he slipped inside Summer’s skin, the dead woods came to sudden life. Where before there had
>   been silence, now he heard: wind in the trees, Hodor’s breathing, the elk pawing at the ground in search
>   of fodder. Familiar scents filled his nostrils: wet leaves and dead grass, the rotted carcass of a squirrel
>   decaying in the brush, the sour stink of man-sweat, the musky odor of the elk. Food. Meat. The elk sensed
>   his interest. He turned his head toward the direwolf, wary, and lowered his great antlers.
>
> He is not prey, the boy whispered to the beast who shared his skin. Leave him. Run.
>
> ---
>
> The smells were there. Mansmells.
>
> *Ashes*, Bran thought, *old and faint, but ashes*. It was the smell of burnt wood, soot, and charcoal. A
>   dead fire.

The animal is not human; the human's consciousness is in the animal, controlling it.